# I'm using Ajax to Post to the controller in Mvc but my var resets to null in the foreach

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

So Im using this code to fill my container with Posts from the database.

The problem is during the foreach im adding a ID to the onclick for the Like Function. But when I try and use it it has turned into a null. Even though the call stack on chrome claims its not null. Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Html:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        foreach (Contribution ctrib in Model)
        {
            <p>@ctrib.Message.Content @ctrib.Likes @ctrib.Reports</p>
            int TempID = ctrib.ID;
            <a name="link" href="#" onclick="javascript:Like(@TempID);">Like</a>
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Like(link) {

    var MyAppUrlSettings = {
        MyUsefulUrl: '@Url.Action("Like", "TimelinePage")'
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: MyAppUrlSettings.MyUsefulUrl,
        data: link,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Like(int ID)
    {
            Contribution C = new Contribution(ID);
            C.likePost();
            RedirectToAction("TimelinePage");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var ctrib in Model)
    {
        <p>@ctrib.Message.Content @ctrib.Likes @ctrib.Reports</p>
        <a name="link" href="#" onclick="javascript:Like('@ctrib.ID');">Like</a>
    }
}
```

and your javascript code :

```
function Like(link) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Like", "TimelinePage")',
        method: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: { Id: link }
    }).done(function (result) {
         alert(result); 
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that at first but it gives the same problem.